# youtube-dl all the vides under a specified playlist

Tags: youtube-dl

I am learning SICP following [MIT 6.001](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE18841CABEA24090),

A single course could be downloaded handdily with

```
 youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_7mmwpgJHU&list=PLE18841CABEA24090&index=2
```

How could download them all included in a playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `--yes-playlist` long flag youtube-dl will download all videos in a playlist. If you will be downloading over several sessions the use of the `--download-archive` flag to record to a file a list of already downloaded videos may be useful.

Source `man youtube-dl`

> ```
>    --yes-playlist
>          Download the playlist, if the URL refers to a video and a playlist.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   --download-archive FILE
>          Download only videos not listed in the archive file.  Record the IDs of all downloaded videos in it.
> ```